# Object Reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, api, .net-core

I'm building an API application and when I call this service method the way it's below, it just works fine:

```
public IEnumerable<Produtos> GetAll(string term, int page, int pageSize)
        {
            var products = _repository.GetAllProducts().Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();

            return products;
            
        }
```

It returns a List of objects. Fair enough.

But then, when I implement this logic, it fails to retrieve me any data:

```
public IEnumerable<Produtos> GetAll(string term, int page, int pageSize)
        {
            var products = _repository.GetAllProducts().Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();

            List<Produtos> produtos = new List<Produtos>();

            products.ForEach(produto =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(produto);
                    if (produto.Nome.Contains(term))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("if statement");
                        produtos.Add(produto);
                    }
                }
            );
            
            if (!(produtos.Count > 0))
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }

            return produtos;
            
        }
```

Also, the IDE tells me that there is not an instantiated object:

[image]

Strangely, when I debug it, it stops looping over the list when it reaches product.name == "kn"

[image]

Here's my db with random values I did insert into.

[image]

Comment: your code and screenshot is not matching, please check. also `produto.Nome` could be `null`

Comment: Looks like `produto.Nome` or `produto.Categoria` or `produto.Categoria.Nome` doesn't exist. Set a break point at the `if` statement and examine the contents of `produto`. Like @viveknuna said, check your code because it doesn't match the screenshot.

Comment: I just changed the if statement a little bit. But returns the same

Comment: @TimJarosz  I did put more info on the post, take a look

Comment: **Don't call `.ToList()` if the return type is `IEnumerable`!**

Comment: Also: `public IEnumerable<Produtos> GetAll(string term, int page, int pageSize) { return _repository.GetAllProducts().Where(p => p.Nome?.Contains(term) ?? false).Skip((page-1)*pageSize).Take(pageSize); }`

Comment: @PauloVitor you still didn't do the debugging, we can't do this for you. You have to set a breakpoint at the `if` statement and examine the `produto` variable. Does it contain all the properties you are trying to reference? If not, then you have to back up and look at  how the data is being retrieved from the database.